# Count only rows that have the same ID on Microsoft Access Report

Tags: ms-access

What I need is the **Count** column shown below.  In the report, it should only count the number of times  the ID and Name are equal.  This is being done in an MS Access Report and is going to be the last column of the report.  My research has turned up mostly aggregates for the entire page but not for specific records.  From the answers I have seen so far, I believe it is worth noting that this will be going into a **textbox on the MS Access Report.**

```
ID   Name       Count
---------------------
344  Neggly     3
344  Neggly     3
344  Neggly     3
222  Henry      2
222  Henry      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate it with a GROUP BY, and then join this result with the original table.

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Name, v1.Count
FROM Table1 t
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT ID, Name, COUNT(*) AS Count
  FROM Table1
  GROUP BY ID, Name) v1
ON v1.ID = t.ID AND v1.Name = t.Name
```

Comment: MS Access has CTE feature?

Comment: Ya!! Right @popovitsj

Comment: So I would create this query and then reference it in the MS Access textbox?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a subquery wherein you calculate the count per ID/Name combination:

```
SELECT
    <table>.[ID],
    <table>.[Name],
    [countTable].[recordCount] as [Count]
FROM <Table>
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT [ID], [Name], Count(*) as recordCount from <table> GROUP BY [ID], [Name]
    ) as [countTable] on
        <table>.[ID] = [countTable].[ID] AND
        <table>.[Name] = [countTable].[Name]
```

You can either write it like that in the query's SQL view, or create a subquery seperately and reference it with the join in this query. Whatever floats your boat.

Comment: So I would create this query and then reference it in the MS Access textbox?

Comment: I believe you could pick up the value you want if you save this as a query, then in the TextBox properties in the Form Designer, set the Control Source for the textbox using the Expression Builder to point to the field you need. I'm pretty rusty at that part, but I believe that's how it would work.